# Why docker exec is killing nohup process on exit?

Tags: bash, docker, nohup

I have running docker ubuntu container with just a bash script inside. I want to start my application inside that container with docker exec like that:

```
docker exec -it 0b3fc9dd35f2 ./main.sh
```

Inside main script I want to run another application with nohup as this is a long running application:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup ./java.sh &
#with this strange sleep the script is working
#sleep 1
echo `date` finish main >> /status.log
```

The java.sh script is as follow (for simplicity it is a dummy script):

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
echo `date` finish java >> /status.log
```

The problem is that java.sh is killed immediately after docker exec returns. The question is why?

The only solution I found out is to add some dummy `sleep 1` into the first script after nohup is started. Than second process is running fine. Do you have any ideas why it is like that?

[EDIT]

Second solution is to add some `echo` or `trap` command to `java.sh` script just before sleep. Than it works fine. Unfortunately I cannot use this workaround as instead of this script I have java process.

Comment: You do not start a container with `docker exec`, but with a `docker run` and you should have a close look at the directives `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` in a Dockerfile

Comment: I have already running container with different process. With docker exec I want to start a second one. This is continues integration scenario so we want to have more processes in one container.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not an answer, but I still don't have the required reputation to comment.

I don't know why the nohup doesn't work. But I did a workaround that worked, using your ideas:

```
docker exec -ti running_container bash -c 'nohup ./main.sh &> output & sleep 1'
```

Answer (score 9):

Okay, let's join two answers above :D

First **rcmgleite** say exactly right: use

> -d

options to run process as 'detached' background.

And second (the most important!) if you run *detached* process, you **don't needed nohup**!

**deploy_app.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/git/app
git pull
python3 setup.py install
python3 -u webui.py >> nohup.out
```

Execute this inside a container

```
docker exec -itd container_name bash -c "/opt/scripts/deploy_app.sh"
```

Check it

```
$ docker attach container_name
$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  11768  1940 pts/0    Ss   Aug31   0:00 /bin/bash
root       887  0.4  0.0  11632  1396 pts/1    Ss+  02:47   0:00 /bin/bash /opt/scripts/deploy_app
root       932 31.6  0.4 235288 32332 pts/1    Sl+  02:47   0:00 python3 -u webui.py
```

Comment: why do you need "interactive talktoyou"? aka `-it`

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a late response but I will add it here for documentation reasons.

When using nohup on bash and running it with 'exec' on a docker container, you should use

`$ docker exec -d 0b3fc9dd35f2 /bin/bash -c "./main.sh"`

The -d option means:

> -d, --detach               Detached mode: run command in the
>   background

for more information about docker exec, see: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

This should do the trick.